# Keybinding in Anki while reviewing

Tags: javascript, jquery, anki

I use Anki, a software of flashcards to learn a new language.
What my card looks like :
[image: Interface]

I want to use a key on my (physical) keyboard to show/hide additional infos on my card to review my cards faster on iPad.

The problem is that the document element is not focused at first (it is the answer buttons that are), so the keyup event in JS/JQuery doesn't work. I need to touch the iPad screen first to then use my keyboard if I want it to work, which kind of defeats the whole point.

My code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
     var key = e.key;
     if (key == "p") {
        // My Code       
     }
  });  

});
```

I tried $(document).click(), $(document).trigger("click") and $(document).focus() without success. [Other](https://www.reddit.com/r/Anki/comments/gbfykz/javascript_how_to_catch_keyboard_events_while/) [people](https://www.reddit.com/r/Anki/comments/gbfykz/javascript_how_to_catch_keyboard_events_while/) (on Reddit) have had this problem but resolved it with add-ons for Anki − As I would like to make it work on iPad (so no add-on), this is not an option forme sadly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers!